# Get metadata from file that triggered blob trigger Azure function

Tags: azure, data-binding, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions, azure-triggers

I have an blob trigger Azure function that is called every time a new file is added to my blob storage. I get the name of that file as an input automatically. In addition to the name, I need the metadata attached to the given file. I've been looking into data input bindings, but I can't make sense of it. What do I need to do to get the file metadata as an input? Or, even just access it within my function?

```
public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    string result = DoSomethingWithFileName(name);
    var something = DoSomethingWithFileMetadata();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of binding to a `Stream` you can bind to a `CloudBlockBlob`. You can then do

```cs
public static Task Run(CloudBlockBlob myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    string result = DoSomethingWithFileName(myBlob.Name);
    var something = DoSomethingWithFileMetadata(myBlob.Metadata);
}
```

And if you need the stream, you can then call `.OpenRead()` or `.OpenReadAsync()`